# Angular TypeScript NG Zorro radio button event

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

Angular [ng-zorro](https://ng.ant.design/version/9.3.x/components/radio/en) TypeScript initially  disables two input fields and after clicking the first radio button, activates the first input field and disables the second input field, so once it same click the second radio button and the second input field should now be enabled, while the first input field should be disabled.

I wrote the code, but it did not work correctly. Is there a solution for this?

**HTML code**

```
<nz-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <label nz-radio nzValue="option1">Option 1</label>
  <label nz-radio nzValue="option2">Option 2</label>
</nz-radio-group>

<nz-input-group>
  <input nz-input [(ngModel)]="input1" [disabled]="selectedOption !== 'option1'" />
</nz-input-group>

<nz-input-group>
  <input nz-input [(ngModel)]="input2" [disabled]="selectedOption !== 'option2'" />
</nz-input-group>
```

**.ts**

```
selectedOption: string = 'option1';
  input1: string = '';
  input2: string = '';
```

Comment: Your code works fine. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcvpqa?file=src/main.ts) Can you reproduce the issue in StackBlitz?

Comment: The last half of the first paragraph is part incomprehensible. Can you fix it?